# SASS not compiling brackets and not importing

Tags: css, sass

I have come across a strange issue with compiling.

Issue One: Not Importing

Issue Two: Compiling does not produce brackets, but becomes the old SASS syntax

This is style.scss:

```
@import "variables";
@import "buttons";
@import "progressbar";

div.hello {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    a {
        color: #AAAAD3;
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

sass-convert style.scss ../css/style.css

becomes:

```
@import variables
@import buttons
@import progressbar

div.hello
  width: 0
  height: 0
  a
    color: #AAAAD3
    width: 300px
```

For the importing, the file structure with import files are all properly prefixed with underscores (_variables.scss, _buttons.scss etc.).

What could be the issue? I am running Sass 3.2.17 (Media Mark).

Help appreciated and thanks in advance!

**-------- SOLVED -------**

It is a silly mistake; the command I have used

```
sass-convert style.scss ../css/style.css
```

is for converting between SASS and SCSS. Although I specified that it is to be outputted as CSS, it still output it as SASS, with its bracket-less syntax.

The correct way to do it is to simply use

```
sass style.scss ../css/style.css
```

Comment: what if you run `sass-convert -F scss -T css style.scss ../css/style.css` ?

Comment: says Unknown format for sass-convert --to: css

Comment: I made the same mistake. Thank you!